# Ruby map unknown parent-child relationship (composition not inheritance) & get parent/child name or object given one known object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parent-child

Say I want to map an unknown parent-child relationship where I have a known `@object_instance` that's could be itself a parent or a child. I'd like to then see if this `@object_instance` has any parents or children, and get then list the ID(s) appropriately. For example, in pseudo-code:

```
def map_relationships
  if self.has_children
    puts "This object has children named #{self.child.class_name} with ID(s) #{self.children.map(&:id)}"
  end
  if self.has_parent
    puts "This object has a parent named #{self.parent.class_name} with ID(s) #{self.parent.id}"
  end
end
```

Let's say `Company has_many Sites` and a `Site has many Offices`, and `@object_instance` is a Site, then the result of the above method would be:

```
@object_instance.map_relationships
> "This object has children named Desks with ID(s) [5,6,7]"
> "This object has a parent named Company with ID(s) 4"
```

Isi something like this possible? I skimmed through the `public_methods` for both a Class and an instance of it, and couldn't see something obvious.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way, essentially you can construct the above method using `reflect_on_all_associations`, which works like so:

```
# get parent
@object_instance.class.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to)
# returns an array, like below
# [:company]

# get children
@object_instance.class.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many)
# returns an array, like below
# [:desks]
```

Other answers welcome in case there are other nifty ways of doing this